# change bg color of label if input is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello i have a while loop selecting elements from database and i display them as label input. What i want to achive is to change background-color if element is checked. Here is my code but it's not working.

```
html
<label class="m1">
<input class="table" type="checkbox" value="1"  name="masa[]" class="checkbox" >
</label>

<label class="m1">
<input class="table" type="checkbox" value="2"  name="masa[]" class="checkbox" >
</label>

<label class="m1">
<input class="table" type="checkbox" value="3"  name="masa[]" class="checkbox" >
</label>

<label class="m1">
<input class="table" type="checkbox" value="4"  name="masa[]" class="checkbox" >
</label>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.m1').live('click', function() {

        var elem = $(this).find('input:checkbox');

        $('input:checkbox:checked').parent('label').css('background-color', '#B6BF34');

        if( elem.is(':checked') && elem.is(':enabled') ) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#00B0EA');
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: $('input[type=checkbox]:checked')

Comment: Its working for me : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/Px38F/)**

Comment: @shaunakde not working well...

Comment: not working, for some reason i get this error `TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
 

...1&s?1:2&s?3:4&s?2:0),e}},special:{load:{noBubble:!0},focus:{trigger:fun...`

Comment: Use `$('.m1').click(function() {...});` instead of `$('.m1').live('click', function() {..});` live() is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.table').change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? '#00B0EA' : '#B6BF34';
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', c);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UvP3f/)**

Comment: thnx, this is working as intended. I dont know why my code is not right, it should work too