# Changing colour of unchecked checkbox text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to change the label colour of an unchecked checkbox. So far I have jQuery code that only allows one checkbox to be checked. Is there a way so that the unchecked checkbox label text changes to a different colour when the other option is chosen/checked? Here's my HTML:

```
              <label><input class="oneBox" type="checkbox" >Wednesday June 6th</label>

              <label><input class="oneBox" type="checkbox" >Friday June 8th</label>
```

And here's the jQuery for only one box to be checked:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.oneBox').on('change', function() {
               $('.oneBox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                    $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));

      if($(this).is(":checked"))
           $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));
      });
  });
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Is there a way?" Yes. "What is that way"? [Take a look at the documentation for `css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2), or better yet, [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change bg color of label if input is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753926/change-bg-color-of-label-if-input-is-checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the **[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** to be the colour you desire. This can be done through the use of **[`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/)**, as `$('.oneBox').not(this).parent().css('color', 'red')`. Note that if you change the selection, the first selection will stay red in this case. To prevent this, you'll also want to tell the selected element to `inherit` the colour with `$(this).parent().css('color', 'inherit')`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.oneBox').on('change', function() {
    $('.oneBox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    //$('#result').html($(this).data("id"));
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //$('#result').html($(this).data("id"));
      $('.oneBox').not(this).parent().css('color', 'red');
      $(this).parent().css('color', 'inherit');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input class="oneBox" type="checkbox">Wednesday June 6th</label>
<label><input class="oneBox" type="checkbox">Friday June 8th</label>
```

Comment: Not really sure why this would be downvoted, as it directly solves the problem asked by the OP. Happy to improve the answer if you'd let me know what you think is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $('label').addClass('default');
           $('.oneBox').on('change', function() {
            $('.oneBox').not(this).parents('label').removeClass("checked").addClass('oneBox');
            // $('.oneBox').attr('class', 'oneBox');
               $('.oneBox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
               $(this).parents('label').removeClass("oneBox").addClass("checked");
              
      if($(this).is(":checked"))
           $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));
          
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.default {
 color: blue;
}
.checked {
color: red;
}
</style>
<label>
<input class="oneBox" type="checkbox" data-id="Wednesday" >Wednesday June 6th</label>
              <label ><input class="oneBox" type="checkbox" data-id="Friday" >Friday June 8th</label>
              
<div id="result"></div>
```